# Why can't I access classList or innerHTML of childNodes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote a simple program to add and delete li elements from a ul list, but got stuck at making the removal work.

I intend to take user input as names of to-be-deleted lis and if the input match the names of a li, it will be deleted. To do that, I wanted to compare the innerHTML of the input with the element's innerHTML or classlist, so I use a loop to go through that ul list's child.

However, I cant access the childNodes' innerHTML or classList as it doesn't recognize the attribute.

I am new to JS so please correct me anywhere if I am wrong.

This is my HTML:

```
//HTML
    <ul id="course">
        <li class="class">En</li>
        <li class="class">Mat</li>
        <li class="class">Lit</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="add()">Thêm khoa học</button>
    <button onclick="deleteClass()">Xóa khóa học </button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

I tried to check the innerHTML match but it didn't work:

```
//JS 1
let course = document.getElementById('course');
let lop = document.getElementById('course').childNodes;
//add class which is the same as the name of the li element to the element itself
for(let i = 0;i< lop.length;i++){
    lop[i].classList.add(lop[i].innerHTML);//does not recognize classList
}
function add(){
    let content = prompt('enter class you want to add');
    let khoaMoi = document.createElement('li');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(content);
    khoaMoi.appendChild(textNode);
    course.appendChild(khoaMoi);
}

function deleteClass () {
    let tenLop = prompt('enter class you wan to delete');
    for(a; a<lop.length; a++){
        if(lop[a].innerHTML === tenLop){
            course.remove(lop[a]);
        };//does not recognize innerHTML
    }

}
```

Same after checking classList:

```
//JS 2
let course = document.getElementById('course');
let lop = document.getElementById('course').childNodes;
//add class which is the same as the name of the li element to the element itself
for(let i = 0;i< lop.length;i++){
    lop[i].classList.add(lop[i].innerHTML);//does not recognize classList
}
function add(){
    let content = prompt('enter class you want to add');
    let khoaMoi = document.createElement('li');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(content);
    khoaMoi.appendChild(textNode);
    course.appendChild(khoaMoi);
}

function deleteClass () {
    let tenLop = prompt('enter class you wan to delete');
    for(a; a<lop.length; a++){
        if(lop[a].classList.contains(tenlop)){
            course.remove(lop[a]);
        };//does not recognize classList
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) returns both text nodes and HTML elements. Use [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) instead.

```js
let course = document.getElementById('course');
let lop = course.children;
```

If you only need the elements of an array, use [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Also, to remove a child using a method of its parent, use [`.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild). Finally, break the loop if it is guaranteed that there are no duplicated elements.

```js
for (const element of lop) {
  if (element.innerText === tenLop) {
    course.removeChild(element);
    break;
  }
}
```

This would also do, however ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)):

```js
element.remove();
```

Try it:

```js
let course = document.getElementById('course');
let lop = course.children;

function add() {
  let content = prompt('enter class you want to add');
  let khoaMoi = document.createElement('li');
  let textNode = document.createTextNode(content);

  khoaMoi.appendChild(textNode);

  course.appendChild(khoaMoi);
}

function deleteClass() {
  let tenLop = prompt('enter class you wan to delete');

  for (const element of lop) {
    if (element.innerText === tenLop) {
      element.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="course">
  <li class="class">En</li>
  <li class="class">Mat</li>
  <li class="class">Lit</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="add()">Thêm khoa học</button>
<button onclick="deleteClass()">Xóa khóa học </button>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```